# How to add a count up animation inside a component?

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js, vuejs2

I have a Vue2 project with a simple component displaying scores from two teams. This component is able to take the current score and the score from the last game as props (both numbers will always be positive integers). So it's easy to calculate the previous scores. Instead of displaying the current score directly I would like to add a count up animation.

This is what I have so far

```
<template>
  <div>{{ firstTeamCounterValue }} - {{ secondTeamCounterValue }}</div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: {
    firstTeamCurrentScore: {
      type: Number,
      default: 0,
    },
    secondTeamCurrentScore: {
      type: Number,
      default: 0,
    },
    firstTeamMapScore: {
      type: Number,
      default: 0,
    },
    secondTeamMapScore: {
      type: Number,
      default: 0,
    },
  },
  data() {
    return {
      firstTeamCounterValue: 0,
      secondTeamCounterValue: 0,
    };
  },
  created() { // do this for the first run
    this.countUpScores();
  },
  updated() { // do this whenever the props change (score changed)
    this.countUpScores();
  },
  methods: {
    countUpScores() {
      this.firstTeamCounterValue = this.firstTeamPreviousScore;
      this.secondTeamCounterValue = this.secondTeamPreviousScore;

      const countUpInterval = setInterval(() => {
        const firstTeamCurrentScoreReached = this.firstTeamCounterValue === this.firstTeamCurrentScore;
        const secondTeamCurrentScoreReached = this.secondTeamCounterValue === this.secondTeamCurrentScore;

        if (firstTeamCurrentScoreReached && secondTeamCurrentScoreReached) {
          // stop
          clearInterval(countUpInterval);
        } else {
          if (!firstTeamCurrentScoreReached) {
            this.firstTeamCounterValue += 1;
          }

          if (!secondTeamCurrentScoreReached) {
            this.secondTeamCounterValue += 1;
          }
        }
      }, 200);
    },
  },
  computed: {
    firstTeamPreviousScore() {
      return this.firstTeamCurrentScore - this.firstTeamMapScore;
    },
    secondTeamPreviousScore() {
      return this.secondTeamCurrentScore - this.secondTeamMapScore;
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

When running the application I pass in the initial scores. Later on the props change. Unfortunately simply nothing happens. There is no count up animation.

Does someone got an idea how to make it work?

I know a little bit of CSS. If you think I shouldn't use code for this please let me know! But I don't know how I would trigger the CSS animation and pass in the required values whenever the update hook was triggered.

Comment: I didn't test it but the updated hook might help https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#updated

Comment: yes, created and updated should do it

Comment: I was able to reproduce it with this sample code https://pastebin.com/HzkwexeX It seems the upaded hook does not trigger

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could watch your props and have a continuing interval that increment your counter values only when they need to be.

```
<template>
  <div>{{ firstTeamCounterValue }} - {{ secondTeamCounterValue }}</div>
</template>
 
<script>
export default {
  props: {
    firstTeamCurrentScore: {
      type: Number,
      default: 0,
    },
    secondTeamCurrentScore: {
      type: Number,
      default: 0,
    },
    firstTeamMapScore: {
      type: Number,
      default: 0,
    },
    secondTeamMapScore: {
      type: Number,
      default: 0,
    },
  },
  data() {
    return {
      firstTeamCounterValue: 0,
      secondTeamCounterValue: 0,
      firstValueToReach: 0,
      secondValueToReach: 0,
      countInterval: null,
    };
  },
  mounted() {
    this.firstValueToReach = this.firstTeamCurrentScore;
    this.secondValueToReach = this.secondTeamCurrentScore;
    this.countInterval = setInterval(() => {
      if (this.firstValueToReach > this.firstTeamCounterValue) {
        this.firstTeamCounterValue += 1;
      }
      if (this.secondValueToReach > this.secondTeamCounterValue) {
        this.secondTeamCounterValue += 1;
      }
    }, 50);
  },
  unmounted() {
    clearInterval(this.countInterval);
  },
  watch: {
    firstTeamCurrentScore: function (val) {
      this.firstValueToReach = val;
    },
    secondTeamCurrentScore: function (val) {
      this.secondValueToReach = val;
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

Comment: This is unoptimized, because you still call setInterval after the counts have been reached

Comment: Also this will increment indefinitely when `firstTeamCurrentScore` gets updated to a value that is below `firstTeamCounterValue`

Answer (score 1):

Here's what you need:

- A `displayedCount` data property that "follows" a `count` prop
- A `change` method that...

  - ...increment or decrement `displayedCount` based on whether `count` is above or below it
  - ...calls itself recursively
  - ...does not call itself when `displayedCount` has reached `count`
- A call to the `change` method when the element is created
- A call to the `change` methods whenever the `count` prop update

You might find ways to make it work with setInterval, but I find that a recursive setTimeout is better here.

Here is some working code. Update the number value in the input and observe the number displayed by `Count` make a count-up animation:

```js
Vue.config.productionTip = false;

const Counter = {
  template: `<span>{{ displayedCount }}</span>`,
  props: ['count'],
  data() {
    return {
      displayedCount: 0
    }
  },
  created() {
    this.change();
  },
  watch: {
    count() {
      this.change();
    }
  },
  methods: {
    change() {
      if (this.displayedCount === this.count) return;
      if (this.displayedCount < this.count) this.displayedCount++;
      if (this.displayedCount > this.count) this.displayedCount--;
      setTimeout(() => this.change(), 200);
    }
  }
};

const App = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  components: { Counter },
  template: `
    <div>
      <input type="number" v-model="count">
      <Counter :count="count"/>
    </div>
  `,
  data() {
    return {
      count: 0
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```

You asked in your question to have one component keep track of two scores. I find it more elegant to have one `Count` component keeping track of one score and possibly another `Counts` component keeping track of two scores using two `Count` components internally. This part is trivial and so I'll let you do it ;)